# SQL 2005 XML Schemas - Defining a Unique Attribute

Tags: sql-server-2005, attributes, xsd, unique

Here's a Sample xml document I'm trying to create a schema for:

```
'<Fields>
  <Field ID="-1">somevalue</Field>
  <Field ID="-2" />
  <Field ID="-3" />
  <Field ID="-4">Some other value</Field>
  <Field ID="-5" />
</Fields>'
```

I'm trying to create a SQL Server 2005 schema collection to:
1. prevent dupicate id's.
2. only allow negative ids.

I can achieve the negative constraint with type="xs:negativeInteger" for the id attribute. But I can't create a unique constraint or key\keyref in SQL 2005.  If I set my type="xs:ID", then I cant use numbers at all for my ID values, nevermind negative IDs.

Either I'm missing something, or its not possible.  If its not possible, why would SQL 2005 not support the ability to have a unique attribute?  Is there a work around using a constraint\trigger or an xml index on the table, or some other technique that I cant even imagine right now?

All help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution using ["unique"](http://www.w3.org/TR/2004/REC-xmlschema-1-20041028/structures.html#cIdentity-constraint_Definitions) ("key" also works):

```
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xs:element name="Fields">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element maxOccurs="unbounded" ref="Field"/>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>

    <xs:unique name="nearlyID">
      <xs:selector xpath=".//*"/>  
      <xs:field xpath="@ID"/>
    </xs:unique>
  </xs:element>


  <xs:element name="Field">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:simpleContent>
        <xs:extension base="xs:string">
          <xs:attribute name="ID" type="xs:negativeInteger"/>
        </xs:extension>
      </xs:simpleContent>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

It validates your example, and gives errors for:

1. duplicate id's
2. id's that aren't negative integers.

Here's your eg plus tests:

```
<Fields>
  <Field ID="-1">somevalue</Field>
  <Field ID="-2" />
  <Field ID="-3" />
  <Field ID="-4">Some other value</Field>
  <Field ID="-5" />

  <Field ID="-2"   >  not unique   </Field>
  <Field ID="2"    >  not negative </Field>
  <Field ID="hello">  not integer  </Field>
</Fields>
```

*EDIT* I have no idea if this is the best way or even if it's a good way.  It works, but I think there's might be a simpler, more straightforward way.

Comment: Though your solution is valid xsd and would achieve the rules I need to enforce, it doesn't work with SQL Server 2005.  'unique' is not supported apparently, neither is 'key'.

Comment: :-(  really?  But it's in the spec - see the link I gave.  uh... that's for the "second edition", maybe they only support the first edition?  No - it also has unique/key: http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/REC-xmlschema-1-20010502/#cIdentity-constraint_Definitions
So I guess they simply didn't implement the whole spec.

Comment: so my question is still out there, how can I enforce that my ID is unique and negative in SQL 2005.

"<xsd:include>, <xsd:key>, <xsd:keyref>, <xsd:redefine>, and <xsd:unique> SQL Server does not support these." ...see here http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190665(SQL.90).aspx

Answer (score 0):

This is an old post, but still relevant today as the unique syntax is not supported (and does not need to be with the answer below).

What you will need to do is create a schema bound scalar function that will pull out the value you want to be unique.

Then you create a persisted computed column on the table containing the xml column. This computed column will execute the schema bound function defined above.

Finally, you define a unique constraint on the persisted computed column. Now it is not only guaranteed unique, but also indexed for fast searching.

EDIT -

This works for top level attributes that need to be unique across multiple rows.

If you need uniqueness within a collection of elements in a single xml document, the approach is similar.

You create a function that takes the xml data type in as the parameter, and has a return value of BIT.

You then use xpath on the xml data type to check uniqueness yourself. If values are unique return 1, if not return 0.

Finally, you add a check constraint to the table that calls the scalar function and verifies the result is 1.